# Intent not repeated by AlarmManager

Tags: android, android-intentservice

Here's my BootBroadcast

```
public class BootBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String FILE_NAME = "BootBroadcast.java";
    private static final long REPEAT_TIME_TO_CHECK_EXPENSES = 1000 * 60; //1 minute

@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.v(FILE_NAME, "in onReceive");
        AlarmManager service = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent service1 = new Intent(context, ISCheckExpenses.class);
        Log.v(FILE_NAME, "starting service1");
        context.startService(service1);

        PendingIntent pending1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, service1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal1.add(Calendar.SECOND, 600);
        service.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal1.getTimeInMillis(), REPEAT_TIME_TO_CHECK_EXPENSES, pending1);
    }
}
```

And here's my ISCheckExpenses

```
public class ISCheckExpenses extends IntentService {
public static final String FILE_NAME = "ISCER";
private int recurringExpensesNotificationID = 001;
private int recurringExpensesMultiplier = 123;

public ISCheckExpenses(){
        super(ISCheckExpenses.class.getName());
    }

@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate(); 
    }

@Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent){

        Log.d(FILE_NAME, "IntentService Started!");

     //do some processing and send a notification to the user
    String subject, content;
    subject = getString(R.string.recurring_expenses_notification_due_subject);
                content = getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.recurring_expenses_notification_due_content);
     sendNotification(recurringExpensesNotificationID,1,subject,content);
    }

    private void sendNotification(int notificationID, int notificationType, String subject, String content){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        int randomID = 1;

            myIntent.putExtra("intentCaller","expensesRecurring");
            randomID = recurringExpensesMultiplier * requestID;

        //just to make sure the random ID is non-negative
        if (randomID < 0){
            randomID = randomID * -1;
        }
        myIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), randomID, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder n  = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle(subject)
                .setContentText(content)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        n.build().flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notificationManager.notify(notificationID, n.build());
    }
}
```

And both files are already inside my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
<service
            android:name=".ISCheckExpenses"
            android:exported="false"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:enabled="true" />
<receiver android:name=".BootBroadcast" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
</application>
```

Few seconds after I restart my device, the notification will be displayed. Then I click on the notification to clear it. And my app is suppose to re-display the notification after 1 minute right? But it doesn't. And I expect to see "IntentService Started!" every 1 minute in my logcat.. but nothing appears? "IntentService Started!" is only displayed once.

What am I missing here? Thanks

Btw I tested this on KitKat and Lollipop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was I mis-understood BroadcastReceiver and AlarmManager should work. Instead of executing the AlarmManager in onReceive as I did above, I should have created another function which calls new Intent and passes the calling activity as the Context, and the BroadcastReceiver as the class.

So here's how my working BroadcastReceiver looks like:

```
public class BootBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

    //private static final long REPEAT_TIME_TO_CHECK_EXPENSES = 1000 * 30;
    //private static final long REPEAT_TIME_TO_ANALYZE_LOCATION = 1000 * 30;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        int what = intent.getIntExtra("what",0);

        if (what == 1) {
            Intent intentService1 = new Intent(context, ISCheckRecurringItemsAndCC.class);
            context.startService(intentService1);
        }else if (what == 2) {
            Intent service2 = new Intent(context, ISCheckLocationAndRating.class);
            context.startService(service2);
        }else{
            //should only reach here when the device boots
            Intent intentService1 = new Intent(context, ISCheckRecurringItemsAndCC.class);
            context.startService(intentService1);

            Intent service2 = new Intent(context, ISCheckLocationAndRating.class);
            context.startService(service2);
        }
    }

    public void setAlarm(Context context){
        Log.v(FILE_NAME,"inside setAlarm");
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, BootBroadcast.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("what", 1);
        PendingIntent myPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 111, myIntent, 0);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), REPEAT_TIME_TO_CHECK_EXPENSES, myPendingIntent);

        myIntent = new Intent(context, BootBroadcast.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("what", 2);
        myPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 222, myIntent, 0);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), REPEAT_TIME_TO_ANALYZE_LOCATION, myPendingIntent);

    }
}
```

The code above is working perfectly for me now.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you are trying to start your `Service` using a `PendingIntent` for a broadcast. You'll need to have the alarm send a broadcast to another `BroadcastReceiver`, since you wish to wake up the device, then have that receiver start your `Service`. You'll also likely need to coordinate with wake locks to ensure the device stays awake long enough.

Comment: I've tried changing it to AlarmManager.RTC but the problem still persists... By the way sorry for the late reply, because I got my intent service to work few days ago. What I did was, I just rearranged contents of my AndroidManifest.xml. I thought I got it all figured out, but suddenly yesterday this problem persists again - my intent isn't being repeated by the alarmmanager

Answer (score 1):

You get the first "IntentService Started!" because you explicitly call `startService()` from your BootReceiver, but your Alarm Manager is set to fire after 10 minutes, not after 1 minute for the first occurrence because you do:

```
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal1.add(Calendar.SECOND, 600);
service.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal1.getTimeInMillis(), REPEAT_TIME_TO_CHECK_EXPENSES, pending1);
```

i.e. you're adding `600` seconds (10 minutes) to the current time and use that for the time at which the AlarmManager should first fire.  Rather than just changing the time you add from 600 to 60 seconds, I'd change the `BroadcastReceiver`, so that instead of calling `startService()` and setting the first time of invocation, I'd just pass the current time in milliseconds to the `AlarmManager.setInexactRepeating()` for the `triggerAtMillis` time so that it triggers immediately, then at your 60 second intervals - i.e. change the `onReceive()` method to:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.v(FILE_NAME, "in onReceive");
    AlarmManager service = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent service1 = new Intent(context, ISCheckExpenses.class);
    Log.v(FILE_NAME, "starting service1");
    context.startService(service1);

    PendingIntent pending1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, service1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    service.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), REPEAT_TIME_TO_CHECK_EXPENSES, pending1);
}
```

You should also remember that as you're using [`setInexactRepeating()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)), the alarms could be delayed by up to a further 60 seconds as described in the documentation.

Comment: Sorry this still doesn't solve my problem. By the way sorry for the late reply, because I got my intent service to work few days ago. What I did was, I just rearranged contents of my AndroidManifest.xml. I thought I got it all figured out, but suddenly yesterday this problem persists again - my intent isn't being repeated by the alarmmanager